# Loading image into Image UI item in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I am trying to load a picture into the Image UI item of my win8 app. But so far i couldn't get the picked image to show on the UI.
  can somebody please tell me how the proper way of doing it?

```
            Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker OpenPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
            OpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            OpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile picture =  await OpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();


            imgPreview.Source = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(picture.Path, UriKind.Absolute));

            imgPreview.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
            imgPreview.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
```

Answer (score 1):

See my post on this [here](http://windows8applicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2012/09/loading-resources.html).

It should be something like this:

xaml:

```
<Image Margin="5" Source="{Binding BMImage}" Height="100"/>
```

C#:

```
BitmapImage bmImage;
public BitmapImage BMImage
{
    get
    {
        return bmImage;
    }
}

bmImage = new BitmapImage();

bmImage.UriSource = new Uri(new Uri(
     Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Path + "\\" +
     Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Name), 
     "favicon.scale-100.ico");
```